# Calculate distance while walking between a fixed point and my current location in iOS

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have to calculate the distance between two locations in iOS and objective c. My one location is fixed at a point and when I walk I have to calculate a distance between my current position and the fixed point. I have used **distanceFromLocation** method but I am not getting the closer distance value. I have gone through a few articles and a few StackOverflow solutions but none gave me proper result.

Below is the code I used and in the code currentLocation and destinationLocation are properties to hold latitude and longitude of the locations. The destinationLocation is always a fixed location and currentLocation keep on changing when I walk. There are few UILabels to print current and fixed latitude and longitude values. I have to calculate the distance every time between these two points. When I move half or less meter it shows me a large distance which is inconsistent as well. Could you please help me what mistake am I doing here? Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks!

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
    CLLocation *newLocation = locations.lastObject;
    self.currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    if(self.destinationLocation == nil){
        self.destinationLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.destinationLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.destinationLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.destinationLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.destinationLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }

    self.currentLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    self.currentLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [self.currentLocation distanceFromLocation:self.destinationLocation];
    self.gpsDistanceMeasurement.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f m", distance];
}
```

Comment: To have better result you should have set this: locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation (swift)

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. I have tried with both with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation and kCLLocationAccuracyBest but getting the similar result. When I am going far away from the fixed point, it's showing at least increasing distance values but when I am going closer, it's even doesn't decrease the distance as of the increasing radio.

Answer (score 0):

you can use haversine formula to calculate the distance between two points

**swift 3.x**

```
let Source = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
let Destination = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

func DistanceCalculator(Source:CLLocationCoordinate2D,Destination:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double
{
    // HaverSine Formula to calculate Diastance On Sphere Refrences//https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
    // Angle = sin2(∆Ø/2) + cosØ1 * cosØ2 * sin2(∆ø/2)
    // constant = 2 * atan2(√angle,√1-angle)
    // distance = R * c
    let Earth_Radius:Double = 6371 * 1000
    let LatDelta = self.DegreeToRad(Degree: (Destination.latitude - Source.latitude))
    let LongDelta = self.DegreeToRad(Degree: (Destination.longitude - Source.longitude))
    let latRad = self.DegreeToRad(Degree: Source.latitude)
    let longRad = self.DegreeToRad(Degree: Destination.latitude)

    let Angle = (sin(LatDelta/2) * sin(LatDelta/2)) + (cos(latRad) * cos(longRad) * sin(LongDelta/2) * sin(LongDelta/2))
    let constant = 2 * atan2(sqrt(Angle),sqrt(1-Angle))
    let Distance = Earth_Radius * constant
    return Distance
}


func DegreeToRad(Degree:Double) -> Double
{
    return Degree * (Double.pi / 180)
}
```

Comment: I am not using any MapKit and in that case how to get CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Comment: what are you using then?

Comment: I have one fixed place with given latitude and longitude and I am getting my current location (every time when a walk) using the didUpdateLocations method as in my given code sample and calculating the distance. I don't need any map in my app.

Comment: then you can create CLLocationCoordinate2D using that lat long

Comment: i have update my answer you can check that and CLLocationCoordinate2D is part of core location not MapKit